# Command substitution: cat with executable content

Tags: bash, shell, cat, command-substitution

I have a file called `test` and the contents are:

```
ubuntu@regina:~$ cat test
** test **
```

catting this file via command line works fine, but if I use command substitution I get an understandable but undesirable result.

```
ubuntu@regina:~$ A=$(cat test)
ubuntu@regina:~$ echo $A
deployment detect.sh htpasswd.py logs test uwsgi-1.0.4 uwsgi-1.0.4.tar.gz test deployment        detect.sh htpasswd.py logs test uwsgi-1.0.4 uwsgi-1.0.4.tar.gz
```

Because of the asterisks that exist in the file `test` it basically executes an `echo *` and lists the directory contents along with the file contents.

Is there a parameter I can pass to the command substitution syntax that will not provide this result, or is there another idiom that should be used for this?

Comment: Note: using cat to read a single file is less efficient then reading the file, example: `A=$(cat test)` VS. `A=$(<test)`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that about that idiom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to do `echo "$A"`. Wrapping the variable in the quotes makes it a string.

Example:

```
[root@talara test]# A=$(<test)
[root@talara test]# echo $A
FILE1 ham test test FILE1 ham test
[root@talara test]# echo "$A"
** test **
```

Comment: Thanks tim! That's exactly what I was looking for. Funny, I knew about quotes and now that I see the answer I feel pwned.

Comment: no prob. Shell quotes are like that, I forget often as well!